# Найти MAC адреса подключенных устройств

Tags: java, android, wifi

Всем привет! Есть телефон который раздаёт Wifi. Необходимо получить список всех MAC адресов подключённых к данному телефону. + проверить перед этим включена ли раздача wifi с телефона. Прошерстил интернет и не нашёл ничего толкового (честно искал). Надежда на вас осталась <3

**UPD**

Сделал вот так, но теперь isReachable() возвращает false, даже когда устройство подключено. Что не так?

```
public void getListOfConnectedDevice() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            boolean isFirstLine = true;

            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (isFirstLine) {
                        isFirstLine = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                    String[] splitted = line.split(" +");

                    if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {

                        String ipAddress = splitted[0];
                        String macAddress = splitted[3];

                        boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(
                                splitted[0]).isReachable(500);  // this is network call so we cant do that on UI thread, so i take background thread.

                        Log.d(TAG, "isReachable: " + isReachable);
                        if (isReachable) {
                            Log.d("Device Information", ipAddress + " : "
                                    + macAddress);
                            macAddresses.add(macAddress);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

**UPD**

Всё работает. Не работало только с тем девайсом с которым тестил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В манифесте добавьте `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`

```
public List <String> getClientList() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Method method = null;
    try {

        method = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getWifiApState");
        method.setAccessible(true);

        // Проверка актуального состояния соединения
        int actualState = (Integer) method.invoke(wifiManager, (Object[]) null);
        if (actualState == AP_STATE_DISABLED ){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Access point is not enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            // Список мак адресов подключенных устройств
            List<String> connectedDevices = new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader br;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
                if (splitted != null) {
                    String mac = splitted[3];
                    if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                        connectedDevices.add(mac);
                    }
                }
            }

            return connectedDevices;
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | IOException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Не знаю почему, но если устройство отключается, он всёравно находит его mac адрес.

Comment: @НикитаШаврин потомучто все зависит от обновления arp таблицы... есть еще 2 варианта как можно это сделать

Comment: @LexHobbit а не подскажешь где можно найти инфу об этом?

Comment: надо Вам читать про iw,iwlist,hostapd. Arp кеш не показывает подключенные устройства, показывает всё устройства с которыми связь была нелавно по эзернет.

Comment: `iw dev wlan0 station dump`